# Xcode Server Integration - Access Post Object from Before-Integration Trigger

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, xcode-bots

I'm using Xcode server 5 for Continuous Integration. I created a Bot that I can trigger via a POST request to: https://server.mycompany.com:20343/api/bots/_some_bot_id_/integrations the Body of this POST request looks like `{ myVariable: "hello", buildBranch: "feature1" }`. Is there a way I can access "myVariable" or the "buildBranch" variable values from within any of the Trigger Scripts that I have added Before and After Integration?

Comment: Have you already tried anything?

Comment: Well, yes: Instead of sending the POST request directly to server.mycompany.com:20343, I send the request to another service who forwards the request to :20343, BUT also saves the needed parameters to a file on disk which I then source from the scripts! Dirty solution but it does the job for now.